# Average Database Query Time

Tags: ios, database, parse-platform

What is an acceptable range of execution times for a complex database query for a production web-application? I'm developing an iOS application with Parse as my cloud db. I've been testing some of my queries and they've been around 150-400 ms. This seems a bit higher than I would have expected, particularly because I am testing at development levels with not many users. When does a large execution time become a burden on the system given large use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depend, how the app will be using the server. 150-400 ms seems ok. If it becomes too long, you can consider to cache the data in the app or do the requests in the background.

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience with these type of systems - will the response time become significantly longer when the number of users grows a lot?

Comment: You didn't specify which type of server do you use. If you use some cheap web hosting, probably thousands of users "crash" the server. If you use some cloud solution, which grow with number of users using it, you should be safe.

Comment: I'm using Parse, which is a big NoSQL SaaS service owned by Facebook. It occasionally has issues but overall they seem pretty reliable. Sounds like it should be fine according to your responses. Thanks for the help.